# Connection Type not visible in Airflow connections

Tags: postgresql, airflow, connection, airflow-connections

I have installed Airflow in Local compluter using wsl2 where airflow is running on localhost:8080

i want to setup connection (name : postgres_localhost) to postgresql which is again installed in local but connection type Postgres is not visible when I am trying to setup connection in airflow

I have installed requried library (apache-airflow-providers-postgres)as well and restart the airflow

Can someone please suggest how can i setup connection to postgressql

```
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator

postgres_task = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='postgres_task',
        postgres_conn_id='postgres_localhost',
        sql='SELECT * FROM localuser'

)
```

I tried to used connection type Sqlite but it fails with error "sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file"